# One Users Email not working for 'test'

Tags: email

I am getting a strange error, though I may be missing something really obvious.
This is the first user I have added, so it may be my error.

Our mailer is set up for SMTP, and it works just fine for everything, but a user was getting a 550 error when sending a test email to themself. 
I have triple checked the email address, it is entered correctly.

Is there somewhere that I have to add this email in CiviCRM in order to have tests work for them?

Using: 
CiviCRM 4.6.24

Attempting from:
Mailings > New Mailings

> Error in call to Mailing_send_test : Failed to add recipient: "EMAIL ADDRESS 
>   HERE" [SMTP: Invalid response code received from SMTP server while sending email. 
>   This is often caused by a misconfiguration in Outbound Email settings. Please 
>   verify the settings at Administer CiviCRM >> Global Settings >> Outbound Email >
>   (SMTP). (code: 550, response: 5.1.1 : Recipient address rejected: User unknown in 
>   relay recipient table)]

Response to Jon G:

I don't think it is the server, i can go check the logs though...
The test works for user1@example.org, user2@example.org, user1@aliasforexample.org, etc. 
It just doesn't work for one particular user.

:::::::::::: SOLVED ::::::::::::

I had to add the user to our relay. I wasn't aware that we were using a relay. :P

Comment: What version of CiviCRM are you using?  How are you triggering the test mail (which screen)?

Answer (score 1):

I think that message is telling you that the email that your smtp server is trying to send to is "EMAIL ADDRESS HERE", which is clearly a placeholder that needs to be filled in. I'd check the record of the contact who is unable to send themselves a test email for fishy bits (e.g. the primary email address, which perhaps got set via an import). If that record looks good, then I'd guess that the email address it's sending to is something unusual for the mail host machine and has a badly configured forward or something like that.

But no, you don't need to do anything special to enable test emails.

Answer (score 0):

I would correlate this with the SMTP mail logs.  My guess is that you're not actually delivering to the server you think you're delivering to.

For instance - is the user's email address using the same domain as a site hosted on the server?  E.g. if I'm "jon@example.org" and I'm using a site that hosts "example.org", it's quite possible that my MTA (mail sending program) thinks it's supposed to deliver email to "example.org" addresses to itself, instead of to an outside address.  If you're using `postfix`, check the `mydestination` setting in `main.cf` to see if that's your problem.

I would also install `swaks` on the CiviCRM server and send an email to the test address and see if there's anything fishy in the transaction.